# Using IntelliJ, how to add dependency in an sbt project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dependencies, sbt

I'm new to sbt and I wanted to learn it with a small Scala project in IntelliJ.

I started with the official sbt Getting Started guide, to learn the sbt basics on the console (https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html). Following the guide, everything compiles fine.

Then I created an sbt project in IntelliJ, trying to do the same thing there. When I add the *org.scalatest* depenpency to the build.sbt file the project can no longer compile. The error message is:

```
module not found: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.13;3.0.5
```

When I created the fresh sbt project in IntelliJ, first the *build.sbt* looked something like this:

```
name := "sbtTest"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.13.0"
```

Then I added the dependency:

```
name := "sbtTest"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.13.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % Test
```

After reloading the build file and getting the error when compiling, I tried to change the *biuld.sbt* according to the code which already worked in the sbt Getting Started guide:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.0"
ThisBuild / organization := "me"
ThisBuild / version := "1.0"

lazy val sbtTest = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "sbtTest",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % Test
  )
```

This has again the same error after reloading and compiling.

My sbt version is 1.2.8.

Is something wrong with my *build.sbt*? Or is the sbt version too new for IntelliJ? Is IntelliJ probably not the recommended IDE to create Sala sbt projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Structure of both your `build.sbt` is ok. The thing seems to be in versions.

Scalatest 3.0.5 is currently unavailable for Scala 2.13.0. It's available for Scala 2.13.0-M2.

It's Scalatest **3.0.8** that is available for Scala 2.13.0.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest

After you fix versions in `build.sbt` re-import IntelliJ project in pop-up window

[image: pop-up window]

or in sbt tool window

[image: sbt tool window]

or in sbt shell

[image: sbt shell]